# Why JSON data from decoder to become UITableView datasource does not assigns?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Recently got stuck on a problem of assigning freshly downloaded JSON data to table view datasource variable. I suppose the problem is something obvious but my skill is not enough to gather the big picture. Let me share a bunch of code.

**(1) A function retrieves the data from Open Weather Map API (defined in the separate class 'GetWeather').**

```
func getMowForecast(completion: @escaping ((WeatherForecast?, Bool)) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=b3d57a41f87619daf456bfefa990fce4&units=metric")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherForecast.self, from: data)
                completion((json, true))
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion((nil, false))
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Everything works fine here. JSON loads correctly and fits the data model.
Here's a link to JSON data to be displayed in tableView: https://pastebin.com/KkXwxYgS

**(2) A controller handles the display of retrieved JSON data in tableView format**

```
import UIKit
class ForecastViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableV: UITableView! // tableView outlet in the IB

    let weatherGetter = GetWeather() // object to handle the JSON retrieval

    var tableData: WeatherForecast? // tableView data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableData?.list.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableVCCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = "\(self.tableData?.list[indexPath.row].dt)"
        cell.tempLabel.text = "\(self.tableData?.list[indexPath.row].main.temp)"
        cell.feelsLikeLabel.text = "\(self.tableData?.list[indexPath.row].main.feels_like)"
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        tableV.delegate = self
        tableV.dataSource = self

        weatherGetter.getMowForecast { (data, status) in
            if let data = data, status {
            } else if status {
                print("-------- Ошибка разбора данных прогноза погоды --------")
            } else {
                print("-------- Ошибка получения данных прогноза погоды --------")
            }
            self.tableData = data
            print(self.tableData)
        }

        print(self.tableData?.list.count) // returns nil

        self.tableData = weatherGetter.getMowForecast(completion: ((tableData, true))) // error - Cannot convert value of type '(WeatherForecast?, Bool)' to expected argument type '((WeatherForecast?, Bool)) -> Void'
    }
    }
```

**The problem is - the table view gets nil datasource so it is unable to load the data and shows the blank screen.**

I suppose the mistake is in scope - I try to retrieve the JSON data inside a function and it does not go anywhere else. What I am wondering about is - how comes that assigning the data to self.tableData does not makes any effect?

Could you please help.
Thank you!
Regards

Comment: You need to reload your table view in the closure after you assign `self.tabledata = data`. Remember to dispatch it on the main queue `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableV.reloadData() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all delete

```
print(self.tableData?.list.count) // returns nil

self.tableData = weatherGetter.getMowForecast(completion: ((tableData, true))) // error - Cannot convert value of type '(WeatherForecast?, Bool)' to expected argument type '((WeatherForecast?, Bool)) -> Void'
```

The error occurs because the method does not return anything and the completion handler syntax is wrong. Both lines are pointless anyway due to the asynchronous behavior of `getMowForecast`

Secondly I recommend to declare the data source array as a non-optional array of the type which represents `List`. Then you get rid of all those unnecessary optionals.

```
var tableData = [List]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableVCCell
    let weatherData = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateLabel.text = "\(weatherData.dt)"
    cell.tempLabel.text = "\(weatherData.main.temp)"
    cell.feelsLikeLabel.text = "\(weatherData.main.feels_like)"
    return cell
}
```

To be able to display the data – as already mentioned by others – you have to reload the table view in the completion handler. And assign the data only if `status` is `true`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    tableV.delegate = self
    tableV.dataSource = self

    weatherGetter.getMowForecast { [weak self] (data, status) in
        if let data = data, status {
           self?.tableData = data.list
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self?.tableV.reloadData()
           }
        } else if status {
            print("-------- Ошибка разбора данных прогноза погоды --------")
        } else {
            print("-------- Ошибка получения данных прогноза погоды --------")
        }            
    }
}
```

And consider that the message *Ошибка разбора данных прогноза погоды* will be never displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the table inside the callback as it's asynchronous

```
 self.tableData = data
 print(self.tableData) 
 DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableV.reloadData() }
```